# Generate 10x10 table using jquery

Tags: jquery, append, html-table

I'd like to create a simple 10x10 table with jquery, what's the problem with this code? It creates this (I haven't added tbody, I don't knwo why it's there)

```
<table id="game_table" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
<td>alma</td>
...
<td>alma</td>
</table>
```

Heres the code:

```
        var $game_table = $("#game_table"),
        init = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                $game_table.append("<tr>");
                for(var j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
                    $game_table.append("<td>alma</td>");
                }
                $game_table.append("</tr>");
            }
        };
```

**EDIT:** thanks for the answers guys, but I can make a table like that with javascript, I just really intersted why this code does not work, so please give me a solution for this.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what sort of error you are seeing?

Comment: there's no error I want to get 10 <tr> with 10 <td> in it, now I get 10 <tr> THAN 100 <td>

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way to do that would be with plain JS, and it's not that hard :

```
var gt   = document.getElementById('game_table'),
    i    = 0, 
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    tr   = document.createElement('tr'),
    td   = document.createElement('td');

while (i<10) {
    var _tr = tr.cloneNode(),
        j = 0;
    while (j<10) {
        _tr.appendChild(td.cloneNode());
        j++;
    }
    frag.appendChild(_tr);
    i++;
}

gt.appendChild(frag);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WxeQL/2/)

Comment: Glad to see someone using fragments instead of working directly on the DOM

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing it this way. I think it will fix your problem.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    var tr = "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
        tr += "<td>alma</td>";
    }
    tr += "</tr>";
    $game_table.append(tr);
}
```

But you are also appending after the `<tbody>` and probably should put it inside the `<tr>`.

Comment: yeah that's good, but a waste of memory, anyways I should be able to add and remove cells/rows later so I'd like to know why this does not work

Comment: Try my way. You'll get your `<td>` inside the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
        var $game_table = $("#game_table");
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            var tr=$("<tr></tr>");
            $game_table.append(tr);
            for(var j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
                tr.append("<td>alma</td>");
            }

        }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxWqx/)

Answer (score -1):

OK the solution was quite easy, I appended the TD-s to the table not to the TR-s